# How to cast while Sorting?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sql-order-by

I have   classes **Vehicle** and **class:Car** is inherited from **class:Vehicle** as in below. I have a List which I want to sort using **LINQ** based on a property of Car class (not of vehicle parent class).

```
class vehicle
{
    public String Name {get; set; }
}

class Car:Vehicle
{
    public String ModelName {get; set; }
}

List<Vehicle> vehicleList=new List<Vehicle>();

Car c1 = new Car();
vechicleList.Add(c1); //s note that i am adding **Car** objects

Car c2 = new Car();
vechicleList.Add(c2);
// added 10 such Car objects
```

Then  I want to Sort vehicleList based on CarModel (which is a property of Car, not of Parent class)

I tried the below one but it does not work.

```
vehicleList.OrderBy(c => (Car)c.ModelName)
```

Any help on how to do this?

Comment: Why do you use a `List<Vehicle>` if you need a `List<Car>`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter i am dealing with some legacy code. and has limitations changing..  :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most readable code that does what you want is

```
vehicleList.Cast<Car>().OrderBy(c => c.ModelName);
```

while of course you could also fix the parens and write the same as

```
vehicleList.OrderBy(c => ((Car)c).ModelName);
```

**That said, both of the above will blow up if there is any `Vehicle` in your list that is not a `Car`**. And if that can't happen, then why isn't that a `List<Car>` in the first place?

Comment: what if vehicle list have contains Plane?

Comment: OfType<Car>() will safe in this case
PS: I will always update before comment 8)

Comment: Thanks, This works  for me. I am making small modifications to someone else's code and it is guaranteed in the case that Only Car objects will be there. i went Linq for sorting it is a case of Orderby()ThenBy. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

You have to decide what you want to have:

A list of `Car` instances or a list of `Vehicle` instances.

If you want to have a list of `Vehicle` instances you can't order by properties of `Car`, because in a list of `Vehicles` there also could be a `Bus` or a `Bicycle`.
Doing what you currently try (casting to `Car`)  will possibly throw an exception at runtime.

Having said that, if you insist on doing it, you have to be aware of two things:

1. You need to fix your cast: `vehicleList.OrderBy(c => ((Car)c).ModelName)`
2. You need to be aware that `OrderBy` doesn't perform an in-place sort. `vehicleList` will still be in its original ordering. If you want to have the ordered result in `vehicleList`, you need to assign the result of `OrderBy` to it:

   ```
   vehicleList = vehicleList.OrderBy(c => ((Car)c).ModelName).ToList();
   ```

Comment: what if my list contains only cars ad the cast does not  fail?

Comment: @user2025418 If your list contains only `Car` objects then it should be a `List<Car>` in the first place, rather than a `List< Vehicle >`.

Comment: @Servy yes that make sense but I am trying with legacy code and it has a list<Vehicles>....Changing it would need a lot of effort

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast `c` into a `Car`, not `c.ModelName`.

Try :

```
vehicleList.OrderBy(c => ((Car)c).ModelName)
```

Comment: But that would fail if you had a `Truck` in vehicleList :( +1 though

Comment: Of course it would. Jon and Daniel Hilgarth provide much more details. Thanks for upvoting though :) Note that using `OfType<Car>` wouldn't fail, but would change the statement meaning, as it would not process through every vehicle. This should definitely be a `List<Car>` to ensure correct behavior.

Answer (score 0):

try use:

```
vehicleList.OfType<Car>().OrderBy(c=>c.ModelName)
```

note: 
this returns only cars from yours list

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
vehicleList.OrderBy(c=>((Car)c).ModelName)
```

but beware it will blow up if an item is not actually a car!

A way around that would be:

```
vehicleList.OrderBy<Vehicle, string>(c=>
{
    Car car = c as Car;
    if (car != null)
        return car.ModelName
    else
        return "";
}
```

But if there were 'non-cars' there position would be determined by the empty string in relation to other items in the list.

Comment: This looks interesting! then can i write something like below? vehicleList.OrderBy(c=>
{
    Car car = c as Car;
    if (car != null)
        return car.ModelName;
    else if (c is plane)
        return plane.planeNumber;
}

Comment: it gives the error :    The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderBy<TSource,TKey>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,TKey>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

```
vehicleList.OfType<Car>().OrderBy(c=>c.ModelName)
```

Comment: This is the same as writing `.OfType<Car>()`, only more chatty.