# Order by anonymous method

Tags: c#, .net, linq, compiler-errors, sql-order-by

With respect to [How to cast while Sorting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14938738/linq-how-to-cast-while-sorting/14938786#comment20971222_14938786), I tried one of the answers below.

```
vehicleList.OrderBy(c=>
{
    Car car = c as Car;
    if (car != null)
        return car.ModelName
    else
        return "";
}
```

But it gives compiler error:

> The type arguments for method
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderBy(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try
>   specifying the type arguments explicitly.

What is wrong in this? How to correct?

What I try to achieve is as below:

- Sort by ModelName if the object is of type Car
- Else if object id of type Train, then by TrainName.

Comment: Your code says `Contact`, but you are talking about `Car` and `Train`! What is `uiItems`?

Comment: Sorry I  put the actual program code... I use vehicles as it is simple to understand...will correct now. thanks

Comment: What is the type of `vehicleList`? Usually you should not get this error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This solves the error:

```
var sortedVehicles = vehicleList.OrderBy<Vehicle, string>(c=>
    {
        ...
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

You can ipmplement a comparer like this:

```
var sorted = uiItems.OrderBy(x => x.Contact, new YourComparer ());

public class YourComparer : IComparer<Contact>
{
    public int Compare(Contact? x, Contact? y)
    {
        if (x == y)
            return 0;
        if (x == null)
            return 1;
        if (y == null)
            return -1;
        if (x.Presence == null)
            return 1;
        if (y.Presence == null)
            return -1;

        return return x.Presence < y.Presence ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the suggestion in the question you referenced, to use a Linq `Cast`?

```
var sorted = uiItems.Cast<Contact>()
                    .OrderBy(c => contact.Presence; );
```

Comment: That has different behaviour when some of the items aren't `Contact`s though.

Comment: Maybe TypeOf is better to use here. The collection is expected to have non-Contact values. var sorted = uiItems.TypeOf<Contact>()
                    .OrderBy(c => contact.Presence; );

Comment: @voo: `OfType` doesn't quite have the same behaviour either -- it excludes the objects that aren't `Contact`s from the sorted enumerable.

Comment: But as I understand the example, the func has to do exactly the same thing - compare to Contact type and return filtered ordered Contact collection. If so, the TypeOf<> it more suitable here

Answer (score 0):

Look at the below example:

```
class Item
{
    public int X;
    public string Y;
}

var items = new Item[100];
var ordered = items.OrderBy<Item, string>(i => i.Y);
```

`OrderBy` requires two types. The former is of the enumerable and the latter is used in lambda expression. Additionaly in some cases, the elements of collection that is being used, must be casted. You can use `Cast` method prior to `OrderBy` if you are sure, that all types are of a particular type or `OfType` in order to ommit other types.